# Magento 2 Product Collection Issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am currently facing a very strange issue. Why does Magento returns null for the below code even we have products. What is the best way to load the product collection based on product attributes?

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
        $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
        $collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('id')->addAttributeToFilter('root_product_id', ['eq' => $rootProductSku])->load();
```

Comment: Where you define  $rootProductSku  ?

Comment: this snippet is a part of a function and i am passing $rootProductSku as a function argument.

Comment: Ok, Other solution work for you ?

Comment: @Pawan: After debugging I found that Mgento does not return the collection of products which is set to out of stock and qty 0. This is very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for product collection with filter

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('id')->addAttributeToFilter('root_product_id', ['eq' => $rootProductSku])->load();
```

Comment: I have already tried collection factory but it didn't work.

Comment: actually you did not add code : $productCollection->create() before addAttributeToSelect('id')

Comment: After debugging I found that Mgento does not return the collection of products which is set to out of stock and qty 0. This is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Get collection using **objectmanager** is not good practices, Try with using **construct method**.

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,        
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;    
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('tag', 28);
    return $collection;
}
```

Above **28** is the **ID** of the option of **tag** attribute.